# How to I use multiple selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, sass, odoo

```
<html>
    <head>
        <a href"dynamic link" data=[data-menu-xmlid="testing.testing"]>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="class 1">
    <body>
<html>
```

How can i select "div" and "a" at same time?

Answer (score 3):

**CSS**

```
div, a {
  
}
```

**JS**

```
document.querySelectorAll("div, a");
```

```js
const select = document.querySelectorAll("div, a");
console.log(select);
```

```html
<div class="first">
  <a class="test"></a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can select `both` div and `a` with

```
div,
a{..style goes here..}
```

But this will be applied to all the `div` and `a` tags in the page so you have to include a div element or a section.

```
    section{
    div,a{
        style here
    }
}
```

So it will be apllied to a specific section

Answer (score 0):

YOU CAN SELECT 2 DIFFERENT HTML ELEMENTS by putting both elements in same selector seperated by a `,`

```
div,a {
   background-color: yellow;
}
```

Comment: You need to include a `,` in between for selecting them both. Right now it will select only the `a` element inside `div`.